# 4K graphics problems with Intel NUC11 with Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: drivers, display-resolution, hdmi, intel-nuc

I recently purchased an Intel NUC11 i7. I have been unable to get a stable picture when using the monitor at 3840x2160 @ 60hz. The screen just switches on and off every few seconds when there is any kind of motion on the screen.

I get a stable picture if I drop the resolution to 2560x1440; or if I drop the refresh rate to 30hz.

The same hardware works faultlessly at full resolution/refresh rate with Win 10.

I have been round the houses with Intel customer support (who officially support 20.04 LTS - https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/212516/intel-nuc-11-pro-kit-nuc11tnhi70q.html). They've run out of ideas and are now just saying "if it works with windows, the machine is OK, so its Ubuntu's fault".

I can confirm the following:

1. Bios is updated to the latest version; I have also reinstalled the bios (suggested by intel)
2. i7 processor; 16gb Ram
3. The cable is definitely the right kind evidenced by the fact that it works perfectly with Windows. I have tried multiple cables and ports on the monitor/nuc
4. Have tried both HDMI and Display port
5. Clean install of Ubuntu
6. Have tried latest (21.04) version of Ubuntu, loading off a usb stick, and the problem persists
7. In Bios I have set the IGD Minimum Memory and IGD Aperture Size to maximum values (suggested by Intel)
8. I have run `xrandr --auto` in order to turn off "phantom display" (suggested by Intel)
9. Have manually set the video mode to hdmi in the bios (suggested by Intel)

Here is a dump of system information requested by intel:

```
# SSU Scan Information
Scan Info:
     Version:"1.0.0.0"
     Scan Date:"2021/08/24"
     Scan Time:"08:34:28"

## Scanned Hardware
Computer:
          BaseBoard Manufacturer:"Intel Corporation"
          Bios Mode:"UEFI"
          Bios Version/Date:"TNTGLV57.0057.2021.0609.1529,06/09/2021"
          CD or DVD:"Not Available"
          Platform Role:"Linux richhoward-NUC11TNKv7 5.11.0-27-generic #29~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 11 15:58:17 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux"
          Processor:"11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz"
          Serial Number:"BTTN104003HJ"
          SMBIOS Version:"3.3.0"
          Sound Cards:"HDA-Intel - HDA Intel PCH"
          Sound Cards:"HDA Intel PCH at 0x603d1a0000 irq 189"
          Sound Cards:"USB-Audio - nuraphone"
          Sound Cards:"00"
          System Manufacturer:"Intel(R) Client Systems"
          System Model:"NUC11TNKv7"
          System Type:"x64-based PC"
          - Display
               - "Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])"
                    Adapter RAM:"size=1G"
                    Capabilities:"[40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=0c <?>"
                    Capabilities:"[70] Express Root Complex Integrated Endpoint, MSI 00"
                    Capabilities:"[ac] MSI: Enable+ Count=1/1 Maskable+ 64bit-"
                    Capabilities:"[d0] Power Management version 2"
                    Capabilities:"[100] Process Address Space ID (PASID)"
                    Capabilities:"[200] Address Translation Service (ATS)"
                    Capabilities:"[300] Page Request Interface (PRI)"
                    Capabilities:"[320] Single Root I/O Virtualization (SR-IOV)"
                    Caption:"Intel Corporation Device 9a49 (rev 01) (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])"
                    Device ID:"8086:3003"
                    Driver:"i915"
                    Driver Path:"/lib/modules/5.11.0-27-generic/kernel/drivers/gpu/drm/i915/i915.ko"
                    Driver Provider:"Intel Corporation"
                    Driver Provider:"Tungsten Graphics, Inc."
                    Driver Version:""
                    Flags:"bus master, fast devsel, latency 0, IRQ 188"
                    I/O Ports:"I/O ports at 3000 [size=64]"
                    Location:"pci@0000:00:02.0"
                    Manufacturer:"Intel Corporation [8086]"
                    Power Management Capabilities:"Power Management version 2"
                    Refresh Rate - Current:"59.91"
                    Refresh Rate - Current:"59.96"
                    Resolution:"2560x1440"
                    Resolution:"1920x1080"
          - Memory
               Physical Memory (Available):"9055 MB"
               Physical Memory (Installed):"15565 MB"
               Physical Memory (Total):"17613 MB"
               - "Controller1-ChannelA-DIMM0"
                    Capacity:"16384 MB"
                    Configured Clock Speed:"Not Available"
                    Configured Voltage:"1.2 V"
                    Data Width:"64 bits"
                    Form Factor:"SODIMM"
                    Interleave Position:"First Position"
                    Locator:"Controller1-ChannelA-DIMM0"
                    Manufacturer:"Crucial Technology"
                    Maximum Voltage:"1.2 V"
                    Minimum Voltage:"1.2 V"
                    Part Number:"T16G4SFRA266.M16FRS"
                    Serial Number:"E5E0AAEF"
                    Speed:"Not Available"
                    Type:"Synchronous"
          - Motherboard
               Manufacturer:"Intel Corporation"
               Product:"NUC11TNBv7"
               Serial Number:"BTTN104003HJ"
               Version:"K87766-402"
          - Networking
               Interface enp88s0:"Not Available"
               Interface wlo1:"Not Available"
          - Operating System
               Boot Device:"/dev/nvme0n1p2"
               Last Reset:"up  1:19,  1 user,  load average: 0.56, 0.49, 0.50"
               Locale:"en_GB"
               OS Manufacturer:"Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS \n \l"
               OS Name:"Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS \n \l"
               Page File:"/swapfile"
               Page File Space (Available):"2097148"
               Page File Space (Used):"0"
               Physical Memory (Available):"9053 MB"
               Physical Memory (Installed):"15565 MB"
               Physical Memory (Total):"17613 MB"
               Version:"5.11.0-27-generic GNU/Linux"
               Virtual Memory (Available):"2097148"
               Virtual Memory (Total):"15939096"
          - Processor
               - "11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz"
                    Architecture:"x86_64"
                    Available:"Offline"
                    Byte Order:"Little Endian"
                    Cache Size:"12288 KB"
                    Caption:"11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz"
                    - Characteristics
                         64-bit capable
                         Enhanced Virtualization
                         Execute Protection
                         Hardware Thread
                         Multi-Core
                         Power/Performance Control
                    CPU Speed (Minimum):"1266.478"
                    CPU Speed (Maximum):"4800 MHz"
                    Current Voltage:"0.8 V"
                    External Clock:"100 MHz"
                    Family:"Core i7"
                    - Flags
                         "ACPI (ACPI supported)"
                         "APIC (On-chip APIC hardware supported)"
                         "CLFSH (CLFLUSH instruction supported)"
                         "CMOV (Conditional move instruction supported)"
                         "CX8 (CMPXCHG8 instruction supported)"
                         "DE (Debugging extension)"
                         "DS (Debug store)"
                         "FPU (Floating-point unit on-chip)"
                         "FXSR (FXSAVE and FXSTOR instructions supported)"
                         "HTT (Multi-threading)"
                         "MCA (Machine check architecture)"
                         "MCE (Machine check exception)"
                         "MMX (MMX technology supported)"
                         "MSR (Model specific registers)"
                         "MTRR (Memory type range registers)"
                         "PAE (Physical address extension)"
                         "PAT (Page attribute table)"
                         "PBE (Pending break enabled)"
                         "PGE (Page global enable)"
                         "PSE-36 (36-bit page size extension)"
                         "PSE (Page size extension)"
                         "SEP (Fast system call)"
                         "SSE2 (Streaming SIMD extensions 2)"
                         "SSE (Streaming SIMD extensions)"
                         "SS (Self-snoop)"
                         "TM (Thermal monitor supported)"
                         "TSC (Time stamp counter)"
                         "VME (Virtual mode extension)"
                    ID:"C1 06 08 00 FF FB EB BF"
                    Level 1 Cache:"192 KiB
fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l2 invpcid_single cdp_l2 ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req avx512vbmi umip pku ospke avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg tme avx512_vpopcntdq rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm avx512_vp2intersect md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities"
                    Level 2 Cache:"5 MiB
fpu vme de pse tsc msr pae mce cx8 apic sep mtrr pge mca cmov pat pse36 clflush dts acpi mmx fxsr sse sse2 ss ht tm pbe syscall nx pdpe1gb rdtscp lm constant_tsc art arch_perfmon pebs bts rep_good nopl xtopology nonstop_tsc cpuid aperfmperf tsc_known_freq pni pclmulqdq dtes64 monitor ds_cpl vmx smx est tm2 ssse3 sdbg fma cx16 xtpr pdcm pcid sse4_1 sse4_2 x2apic movbe popcnt tsc_deadline_timer aes xsave avx f16c rdrand lahf_lm abm 3dnowprefetch cpuid_fault epb cat_l2 invpcid_single cdp_l2 ssbd ibrs ibpb stibp ibrs_enhanced tpr_shadow vnmi flexpriority ept vpid ept_ad fsgsbase tsc_adjust bmi1 avx2 smep bmi2 erms invpcid rdt_a avx512f avx512dq rdseed adx smap avx512ifma clflushopt clwb intel_pt avx512cd sha_ni avx512bw avx512vl xsaveopt xsavec xgetbv1 xsaves split_lock_detect dtherm ida arat pln pts hwp hwp_notify hwp_act_window hwp_epp hwp_pkg_req avx512vbmi umip pku ospke avx512_vbmi2 gfni vaes vpclmulqdq avx512_vnni avx512_bitalg tme avx512_vpopcntdq rdpid movdiri movdir64b fsrm avx512_vp2intersect md_clear flush_l1d arch_capabilities"
                    Level 3 Cache:"12 MiB"
                    Load:"load average: 0.56, 0.49, 0.50"
                    Manufacturer:"Intel(R) Corporation"
                    Model:"140"
                    Name:"11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz"
                    Number of Cores:"4"
                    Number of Cores - Enabled:"4"
                    Part Number:"To Be Filled By O.E.M."
                    Socket Designation:"U3E1"
                    Status:"Populated, Enabled"
                    Version:"11th Gen Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-1185G7 @ 3.00GHz"
                    Voltage:"0.8 V"
                    Virtualization:"Not Available"
          - Storage
               - "DataTraveler_3.0"
                    Capabilities:"IORDY not likely"
                    Capabilities:"Cannot perform double-word IO"
                    Capabilities:"R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported"
                    Capabilities:"DMA: not supported"
                    Capabilities:"PIO: pio0 "
                    Caption:"/dev/sda"
                    Cylinders - Total:"0"
                    Description:"ATA device, with non-removable media"
                    Firmware:"Not Available"
                    Heads - Total:"0"
                    Index:"Not Available"
                    Interface Type:"ATA"
                    Manufacturer:"Not Available"
                    Model:"Not Available"
                    Name:"sda"
                    Partitions:"Not Available"
                    Sectors - Per Track:"0"
                    Serial Number:"Not Available"
                    Size:"1024*1024: 0 MBytes"
                    Size:"1000*1000: 0 MBytes"
                    Size - Available:"Filesystem     1K-blocks     Used Available Use% Mounted on"
                    Size - Available:"/dev/sda1       15143456    31816  15111640   1% /media/richhoward/blah"
                    SMART Attributes:""
```

Does anyone have any idea what could be happening?

Comment: What I do not see here is what kernel you are running or if you have upgraded the kernel from the default of a new install. OOPs I see it now hiding in all the other data. 5.11 There is newer that might help.

Comment: I have updated the kernel to the latest officially supported version and it didn't help.

I'm not super keen on updating it to an unsupported version - is that not likely to create other problems?

Comment: What version is that you have upgraded to?

Comment: 5.11.0-34-generic

Comment: Many are using 5.14 and as far as I know it is fully supported.

Comment: I wasn't able to update the kernel on my existing installation. What I was able to do was to boot a daily build of Ubuntu 21.10 off a usb which includes the 5.13 kernel. It didn't help - same problem persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have exactly the same issue and I have to register an account in AU just to add this answer.

My system is also NUC11 i7. My initial installation was Fedora and I got the same problem of random disconnects in HDMI connection when working at 4k/60hz.

I think the problem has something to do with memory installation.

The problem persists with the following tries:

- Replacing Fedora with Ubuntu
- Upgrading BIOS to the latest version (041 as this is written)
- Using USB-C to either HDMI or DP, both front and rear USB-C
- Trying different BIOS video memory configurations

But, interesting enough, *after I added an additional RAM band, the problem got fixed automatically*. My initial setup was just like yours with a single DIMM of 16G installed.

I wish could just add a comment to your question instead of having this added as an answer as I don't know if it really helps in your case.

Comment: Interesting! To clarify, do you mean that you now have 32GB of memory, or have you swapped your 16gb for 2x8gb boards?

Comment: I added an additional, identical SO-DIMM of 16GB. I now have 32GB of memory. I don't have the chance to test if the problem is at the amount of RAM or at the fact that it needs two DIMMs to work.

Comment: Dương Thành An; you're my hero! Problem solved. Thank you so much for taking the time to create an account to help me out. Cảm ơn!